# Cannot find the column after committed update (JDBC, MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I stuck with a strange problem: I do SELECT query to the MySQL 5.1 database, commit UPDATE query and cannot do SELECT query again after it (Java complains that couldn't find the column).

Here is my code:
     //SELECT

```
 dbhIrmdb.setAutoCommit(false);
 PreparedStatement preparedSelect=null;
        preparedSelect=dbhIrmdb.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rowSet=preparedSelect.executeQuery();
        dbhIrmdb.commit();
        while (rowSet.next()) {
            computer=new ComputerInfo();
            computer.setIndex(index); index++;
            computer.setComputers_id(rowSet.getString("computers_id"));
            ....
        }
 dbhIrmdb.setAutoCommit(true);
```

//UPDATE

```
 PreparedStatement commonUpdate=null;
    try {
        String queryUpdate="UPDATE computers SET name=?, serial=?, inv_number=?, comments=?, rack_unit=?, box_unit=?, ram=? WHERE ID="
                +currentComp.getComputers_id();
        dbhIrmdb.setAutoCommit(false);
        commonUpdate=dbhIrmdb.prepareStatement(queryUpdate);
        commonUpdate.setString(1, currentComp.getComputers_name());
        ...
        commonUpdate.executeUpdate();
        dbhIrmdb.commit();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        try {
            System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
            dbhIrmdb.rollback();
        } catch(SQLException excep) {
            excep.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
    finally {
        if (commonUpdate != null) {
            commonUpdate.close();
        }
        dbhIrmdb.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
```

I did deep research through the site, but I couldn't find such case.

I'd be appreciate for any help or advice.

Comment: You are doing so well with using prepared statements and then you have `WHERE ID="+currentComp.getComputers_id()`. Come on, just one little hurdle...

Comment: In the update you have `ID` and in the query you have `computers_id`. I suppose you need to decide which it is. If the update succeeds I would suspect `ID` is the correct one.

Comment: The concatenation in the end of the query looks awful, but I don't want to watch for ID's substitution number when I add a new name=value couple.

Comment: UPDATE query works well. All the SELECT queries don' work after it.

Comment: These are parts of different methods of the same class.

Comment: As i can see you have only one select and one update.I can not see second select

Comment: @AlexanderShalin show us your second query

Comment: First and second SELECT queries are the same. It's just refreshing dataTable.

Comment: @javaBeginner I've added SELECT request, as you see, it looks simple.

Comment: @AlexanderShalin Your code is huge,its difficult to check .Just post only the relevant codes.If you make any updates then do it in separate line or make it in bold.It will be helpful to catch

Answer (score 0):

You've `computers_id` in `//SELECT block` and `ID` in `//UPDATE`.

Try this in //UPDATE block

```
String queryUpdate="UPDATE computers SET name=?, serial=?, inv_number=?, comments=?, rack_unit=?, box_unit=?, ram=? WHERE computers_id="
            +currentComp.getComputers_id();
```

Comment: computers_id is the alias for computers.ID, if I do that, the query will not execute, there is no computers_id field in 'computers' table.

Comment: I guess, you should post Schema structure for Computer Entity or likewise.

Comment: I'll try MySQL 5.7 instead 5.1. I suppose it's because of too old database server version.

Comment: Ok. Let us know the result.

Comment: Nope, the same fail. I don't understand why.

Comment: I reverted changes to the last stable state, all works OK. I think, something wrong is happening with Connection object after prepared UPDATE statement.

Comment: The fail had disappeared when I moved UPDATE prepared statement from dataTable getter to commandButton click event hangler. Very strange, I keep tracking.